# Call by reference not working as expected

Tags: c#, arrays, ref

In the example of Microsoft's web there are below codes:

```
class TestRef
{
    static void FillArray(ref int[] arr)
    {
        // Create the array on demand: 
        if (arr == null)
        {
            arr = new int[10];
        }
        // Fill the array:
        arr[0] = 1111;
        arr[4] = 5555;
    }
}
```

If I delete the line of `if (arr == null)`, the error output will be `0 0 0 0 0` not `1 2 3 4 5`. Why?

Comment: the link of the codes:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/szasx730.aspx

Comment: If you create a `new int[]` array, all elements are initialized to `0`. Is that you asking?

Comment: int is a primitive type, so it will always have the default value which is 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are passing by `ref` this means that you are changing the pointer for that variable in the `main` method.

You are assigning it to a new `int[]` that is filled with the default value of `int` which is 0

Comment: so the output will be 1111 0 0 0 5555 0 0 0 0 0

Answer (score 0):

its happening because when you put your code as it is it mean you are passing your intArray to the method but when you remove the lines as you have mentioned in this case new int[] is assigned to variable which will fill default 0 in your array.

this line  `arr = new int[10];` is assigning new int[] when you remove conditions.

As documented in the official site :-

> A ref parameter of an array type may be altered as a result of the
>   call. For example, the array can be assigned the null value or can be
>   initialized to a different array.

Answer (score 0):

Here in `FillArray` function you are passing the array by reference
but when you remove the `if` block
you re-initialize the array

when you initialize a value type array the elements take default value of the value type
In this case it is `int` which have default value `0`

You need to understand pass by value vs pass by reference in C#
http://www.programminginterviews.info/2011/05/pass-by-value-versus-reference-in-c.html

also value type vs ref type
http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx